# custom backbutton not working in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

i am using these code for custom back button

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button-2.png"];

    //create the button and assign the image
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

and here is the back function

```
-(void)back {   
    // Tell the controller to go back
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Custom back button is coming up, but it's not working.

Comment: What happens when you tap the button?  Does it dim like a regular bar button does?  Or does it not react at all?

Comment: it's showing normal tabbing, but not redirecting.

Comment: Did you try redeclaring your back function as `-(void) back:(id)sender` and add the action as `@selector(back:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the target to the `customBarItem` instead of the `button` custom view

Comment: @Shyantanu use `customBarItem.target = self; customBarItem.action = @selector(back);` instead of `[button addTarget...`

Comment: ed this, but no improuvement .. :(

Comment: @Shyantanu, I don't believe it is still not working, it must work as it is mentioned in the answer because this is the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self getBackBtn];



- (UIBarButtonItem *) getBackBtn
{
    UIButton * backBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,73.0f,33.0f)];
    [backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"back.png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
    return backBarButton;    
}

//Action For LeftBarButton - BackButton
- (void)backBtnPressed
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a custom UIBarButtonItem in a different way, and keep it being arrow-shaped

Say your first controller is A, and you pushed into B, in A controller's viewWillAppear: you can do

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

That will make B's back button a normal back button but having the image you selected

If you want custom text instead, you can do

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

because the `UIBarButtonBarItem` does the event handling itself and **it will never pass the event** to its `UIView`, where your custom back button is. spot in this line, you've added it as a **subview only.**

```
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

it shows but **it will never get any feedback of the events** from the `UIBarButtonItem`, this is a view only, the parent `UIBarButtonItem` won't pass the any event to handle to a simple `UIView`. it would not be logical behaviour, therefore this it is perfectly fine.

---

you have to add the selector the `UIBarButtonItem` like

```
[customBarItem setAction:@selector(back)];
```

not for you `UIButton` object.

---

...or you can add your back button like

```
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(back)]];
```

you can use any other init method of the `UIBarButtonItem` class to customise it, you will find them in the **[UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**.

Answer (score -2):

Try here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

That's what I used.... Basically you add this method to your app delegate:

```
- (void)customizeAppearance
{

    UIImage *buttonBack30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back_textured_30"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack30 
        forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: does not answer the question.  Look at the method name, then look back at the question.